# Using axios to get data from "/get" to "/", but geting 403 error. (Express, mysql, JWT)

Tags: node.js, express, axios, jwt

What I'm trying to do is get json data from "/get" to "/", but I'm not sure why axios keeps giving my a 403 error. From what I read, axios isn't the issue, but cors is. I tried all the ways that people are recommending, but nothing is working. What I'm I doing wrong within my code? I'm also seeing "Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin" in the Header, but I'm not sure if that's what's causing this issue.

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const expressSession = require("express-session")({
secret: "secret",
resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false,
});
const passport = require("passport");

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());

 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(expressSession);

 const axios = require('axios');

 var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "sys",
  multipleStatements: true,
});

 mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
   if (!err) console.log("DB connection succeded.");
   else
     console.log(
       "DB connection failed \n Error : " + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
    );
});

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, GET, POST');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});

app.listen(5000, () =>
  console.log("Express server is runnig at port no : 5000")
);

 app.get("/get", authenticateToken, (req, res) => {

  jwt.verify(req.token, 'secretpassword', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM sys.jobs", (err, rows) => {
        if (rows === undefined) {
          res.send("Hello World!");
        } else {
          res.send(rows);
        }
      });
     }

  });
});

 app.get("/", authenticateToken, (req, res) => {

  jwt.verify(req.token, 'secretpassword', async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {

    let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/' +'get', {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': `Bearer 
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjAwOTIyMTQ0LCJleHAiOjE2MDg2OTgxNDR9.aRsw- 
jEQJ-7mlO10nBKA5VT3IL7P0b9T9K0C8aT8sUs`
  
   }
    });

       res.send(response.data);

    }
  });
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;

    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM sys.users WHERE email = ?", [email], async (error, results) => {

      const id = results[0].id;
      const token = jwt.sign({ id }, "secretpassword", {
      expiresIn: '90d'
    });

  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true
  }

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  res.status(200).redirect("/get");
  });
  }
  catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
}
);


function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {

  const bearerHeader = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {

  req.token = bearerHeader;

  next();
} else {

   res.sendStatus(403);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module

```js
const cors = require('cors')

//... your app instance code here

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: If you look at my code, that's what I did. It's not working.

Comment: you're overriding cors headers please remove and check and provide proper error message

Comment: Do you mean get rid of this. 

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, GET, POST');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});